# What is the meaning of 攻めを自重?

Tags: grammar

I am confused with the phrase 攻めを自重 in the following sentence

> ただ「攻め」を自重しながらも、独特のハイトーンはしっかりと響かせていた。

The sentence is taken from Asahi Simbun article
http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASK6M45BZK6MPTQP00F.html?iref=com_alist_photo

Comment: Probably something like: His dignity as a offense (?) notwithstanding, he sang with a uniquely high pitch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mackygooさんに先手を取られた！全く同感です。

To expand a little more, I think I'd describe 自重{じちょう}する in this context as "exercise self-restraint".

So overall, something along the lines of: "While restraining himself from overly bold behavior, he nevertheless made his unique high pitch singing reverberate throughout the stadium." And here I didn't even know デーモン閣下 could sing.

That having been said, I don't think you're likely to come across 
自重{じちょう}する very often, although figurative usages of 「攻め」to refer to bold, daring, proactive, or even agressive behaviors, attitudes, or approaches come up a lot.

Comment: @mackygoo That was entertaining! Until now, I’d only seen him as a commentator on TV shows every now and again.

Answer (score 3):

> 熱唱した舞台も広いフィールドのど真ん中で、「方々まで走り回りたかったが、あまり遠くまで行くと戻ってこられなくなる」。**ただ「攻め」を自重しながらも、独特のハイトーンはしっかりと響かせていた**。

この文脈から判断すると、「攻め」とは、舞台を下りてフィールドを走り回ることを指し、「自重する」とは、本当は走りたかったが走らずに舞台にとどまって歌ったことを指します。

*Judging from this context*, "攻め" *refers to step down from the stage to the field to run around there*, *and* "自重する" *refers to that he really wanted to run around the field*, *but he patiently stayed on the stage and sang without running around*.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add that the writer of this article probably want to allude to the fact that デーモン閣下 has deep connection to sumo, as 「攻め」also refers to a sumo style (attacking/aggressive); I also notice that when I looked up 攻め in my main Japanese-English dictionary (Kenkyusha 5th ed.), 2 out of 4 example sentences are sumo-related. The title of the article is less subtle about it: "相撲じゃないけど…　デーモン閣下、パールボウルで熱唱"

Comment: 攻め itself is not limited to sumo. It can be used with soccer, basketball chess and so on. (攻撃 might be a bit more common in ball sports, though)